# Save radio button values

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am using model form,

```
TYPE_SELECT = (
    ('0', 'Live'),
    ('1', 'Test'),
)

class ReportForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    type_select = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(
                        renderer=HorizRadioRenderer),choices=TYPE_SELECT)  
    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = ['notes_other','type_select']
```

and my models look like this,

models:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
    type_select = models.BooleanField('Complete', default=True)
    notes_other = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

template is

```
{{ form.type_select }}
```

Now,i want to use this `type_select` field in 5 pages.If user selects the radio button and save in 1st page,it should save and in other remaining pages,it should be applied.

If he wants to change the selected option,he is able to change and save in any of the 5 page,the changes should apply in all pages.

So,i need to display this form in all 5 pages and for every page i need to pass the method to views also.

How to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need a form filled with initial data. How you store that data between page views is up to you but this is typically done in the `session`

Here is how you load initial data into a form.. as in prepopulate that radio button.

```
type_value = request.sesssion.get('type_value')
form = MyForm(initial={'type_select': type_value})
# rest of view
```

Now, upon saving any of these 5 forms, have their views set the session variable 'type_value' to the one submitted to have it persist across requests.

```
if form.is_valid():  # you no doubt have a line like this.
   request.session['type_value'] = form.cleaned_data['type_select']
```